# Getting a fixed accuracy: 0.5000 and sometimes 0.0000e+00 in Keras model using Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, classification

I am training a CNN model using Keras on Google Colab for binary image classification, the problem is when i use Sigmoid function i get accuracy fixed on 0.5000, and when i change metrics to 'acc' i get 0.000e+00 as accuracy. Also, when i change the activation function to 'Softmax' my model start learning.

Ps: i am using google colab where Tensorflow version is 2.5.0

My code:

```
def define_model(input_shape, num_classes):
    model=ResNet50(include_top = False, weights = 'imagenet', input_shape = input_shape)
    x = model.output
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    preds = Dense(num_classes,activation='sigmoid')(x) 
    model = Model(inputs=model.input,outputs=preds)
    return model

def train(epochs):   

    train_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255.0,vertical_flip=True, horizontal_flip=True)                                                                                                                           
    test_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255.0)

    train_generator = train_generator.flow_from_directory(
        'trainset/',
        target_size=(image_size, image_size),
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE_TRAINING,
        seed = 7)

    validation_generator = test_generator.flow_from_directory(
        'testset/',
        target_size=(image_size, image_size),
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE_VALIDATION,
        seed = 7)

    input_shape = (CHANNELS, image_size, image_size) if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first' \
            else (image_size, image_size, CHANNELS) 
            
    model = define_model(input_shape, NUM_CLASSES)

    opt = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-6, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.99, amsgrad=False)

    model.summary()
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=opt,
                  metrics=['acc'])
               
    filepath=path+"weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-vacc:{val_accuracy:.2f}-tacc:{accuracy:.2f}.hdf5"
    '''cb_early_stopper = EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_accuracy', mode='min', verbose=1, patience = EARLY_STOP_PATIENCE)
    cb_checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath = filepath, monitor = 'val_accuracy', save_best_only = True, mode = 'auto')
    reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_accuracy', factor=0.25, patience=5, min_lr=1e-7)'''
    fit_history = model.fit(train_generator,
            epochs = NUM_EPOCHS,
            validation_data=validation_generator,
            verbose=1,
            class_weight=class_weights)
#            callbacks = [cb_checkpointer, cb_early_stopper, reduce_lr],
            
    return model, fit_history
        
def main():
    
    start_time = time()
    model, fit_history = train(epochs=NUM_EPOCHS)    
    end_time = time()
    seconds_elapsed = end_time - start_time
    print('token time: ', seconds_elapsed)
    hours, rest = divmod(seconds_elapsed, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(rest, 60)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved by adding this code to the .flow_from_directory() function:

```
class_mode='binary',
```

Thanks to this thread on github:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/13006